# What is the correct syntax of MIPS instruction sll?

Tags: mips, sll

Should the shift amount be an immediate value, or a value stored in a register? Does both work?

I've had different websites tell me different things and am confused.

Based on my research the sll (shift left logical) instruction should be used like this:

```
  sll $d, $t, h
```

Which makes $d = $t shifted left h times.

I've been told that h should be a immediate value, but I was wondering if a register could be used as the third argument, and the value inside that register used as the shift amount. Would that also work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.

`sll` is specific in that it is a [R-format](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Instruction_Formats) instruction where only two registers are used, rd and rs (destination and source), and the shamt field is a immediate value (a constant).

There is another instruction `sllv` which uses a third register where you specify shift by variable (the register).

Comment: Note: `sslv` is a MIPS32r2 instruction. The MIPS32r2 version of the MIPS architecture was introduced in 2002, so it is not yet supported by common educational tools like SPIM and MARS.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear the point Shift left logical in MIPS 32 bit has following syntax:

**[SLL destination, Target, Shift amount(Should be immediate value)](http://www.assemblylanguagetuts.com/shift-left-logical-mips-sll/)**

Where as in 8086 if we want shift amount more than 1 we have to use a register to store the value of shift amount!